# How to apply CSS to Here Maps API Markers

Tags: css, here-api

Is there a way to apply CSS to custom markers on a Here JS Map? 
We are using version 3.0 of the JS API and I just want to know if there are any selectors I can use or anything along those lines to apply CSS to the markers. I haven't found anything so far.

We are using an SVG marker based on: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers

Thanks

Comment: [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) is an image technology.  It might be possible to apply a colored background to a transparent .png type image via Cascading Style Sheets, but beyond that where are you going with this?

Comment: Are you trying to style the image? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I think OP is displaying SVG map markers using some API and wonders if the web elements they render as have any CSS properties.

Comment: If you call `getBitmap()` you can get the `(HTMLImageElement | HTMLCanvasElement)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you shared uses `H.map.Marker` which is according to [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.Marker.html), a visual representation of a location on a map in the form of a **static bitmap icon**.

For styleable marker you should use `H.map.DomMarker`:

```js
// assuming DOMElement already exists
var domMarker = new H.map.DomMarker(map.getCenter(), {
  icon: new H.map.DomIcon(DOMElement)
})
```

Here is a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvojka/42h9rwq0/) page with DomMarker which changes opacity on hover using CSS rules.

See [DomMarker documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.DomMarker.html) for more details.